# How can +1 a cell value that already has a function applied to it in Google Sheets script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi all I'm completely new to writing scripts (I apologice if i use any incorrect terms) and but managed to cobble this together yesterday, however the function called 'increment' at the end doesn't seem to work as part of this script.

```
function ClearRange() {
//replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
//Inserts a row before populating it
sheet.insertRowAfter(37);
//the next three lines copy a preformatted line and paste it underneath
var source_range = sheet.getRange("A37:V37");
var target_range = sheet.getRange("A38:V38");
source_range.copyTo(target_range);
logData();
//the next lines clear the data form ready for new input
sheet.getRange('B5:D5').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('I5:O5').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('B11:G11').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('I11:P11').clearContent();  
sheet.getRange('B18:D18').clearContent();  
sheet.getRange('I18:K18').clearContent();  
sheet.getRange('B24:F24').clearContent();  
sheet.getRange('I24:M24').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('B31:G31').clearContent(); 
sheet.getRange('K28:Q28').clearContent(); 
}

function logData() {
// This will take the submitted data and put it into the proper row format

//This bit defines the destination cells
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var thedateCell = sheet.getRange("A38");
var QuoteNoCell = sheet.getRange("B38")
var ClientCell = sheet.getRange("C38");
var ContactCell = sheet.getRange("E38");
var AddressCell = sheet.getRange("F38");
var QTOPDCell = sheet.getRange("N38");
var QMBSCell = sheet.getRange("O38");
var QCADDCell = sheet.getRange("P38");
var QTRAVDCell = sheet.getRange("Q38");
var QSODCell = sheet.getRange("R38");

//This bit defines the origin cells
var theDate = sheet.getRange("I28").getValue();
var QuoteNo = sheet.getRange("J28").getValue();
var Client = sheet.getRange("K28").getValue();
var Contact = sheet.getRange("L28").getValue();
var Address = sheet.getRange("M28").getValue();
var QTOPD = sheet.getRange("O19").getValue();
var QMBS = sheet.getRange("P19").getValue();
var QCADD = sheet.getRange("S19").getValue();
var QTRAVD = sheet.getRange("R19").getValue();
var QSOD = sheet.getRange("Q19").getValue();

//This bit transfers the data
thedateCell.setValue(theDate);
QuoteNoCell.setValue(QuoteNo);
ClientCell.setValue(Client);  
ContactCell.setValue(Contact);  
AddressCell.setValue(Address);  
QTOPDCell.setValue(QTOPD);  
QMBSCell.setValue(QMBS); 
QCADDCell.setValue(QCADD); 
QTRAVDCell.setValue(QTRAVD); 
QSODCell.setValue(QSOD);
}
function increment() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('J28');
sheet.setValue(Number(sheet.getValue()) + 1)
}
```

I suspect that this is due to J28 already being subject to the getRange & setValue commands? Increment works if done by itself, however I would like it to work was part of this script so that it all can be done from the one button press within my sheet so that once I've clicked the button everything that needs to be cleared, is cleared and the number in J28 is incremented by 1.

J28 will just contain a number. It is currently something like "181823" I did try putting the increment() at the end of the transfer section of the code as I thought that it might be how the code would behave in saying "once this has been done, then increment"

Can anyone suggest if it is possible to get increment to work once the other events have happened in the script? I might get some sleep tonight is so :-)

Comment: Welcome. What is the value of J28? If you got an error message at it textually to the question.

Comment: Hi Ruben,J28 will just contain a number. It is currently something like "181823" I did try putting the increment() at the end of the transfer section of the code as I thought that it might be how the code would behave in saying "once this has been done, then increment"

Answer (score 0):

Add this, then run `main`:

```
function main(){
  ClearRange();
  logData();
  increment();
}
```

Reference [Calling functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Calling_functions)